# How do I delete the circle of days once the timer has reached zero?

Tags: jquery, html, countdown

```js
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $(".countdown").circularCountdown({
    startDate: "2015/03/01 12:30:00",
    endDate: "2017/11/26 17:15:30",
    timeZone: +1,
  });
});
```

```html
    <section id="multicolor" class="dark-wrapper multicolor">
      <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="countdown multicolor"></div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

How do I delete the circle of days once the timer has reached zero?

The same argument applies also to the hours and tails

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $(".countdown").circularCountdown({
    startDate: "2015/03/01 12:30:00",
    endDate: "2017/11/26 17:15:30",
    timeZone: +1,
  });
});
```

Comment: is this PHP or Javascript or JQuery? you should set the tag. (o*riginal comment was due to code being unformatted*)

Comment: And add some explanation as to what's going on, what you've tried, why it failed?

Comment: [**How to ask a good question on Stack Overflow**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) (and get good answers quickly)

Comment: from what I'm seeing (and purely at a guess), you're using the flashBlue circular countown widget. Check with them for some sort of an API. You're looking for a success or complete callback.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in my comment, you probably want to RTFM for the API you're using. There should be some sort of oncomplete callback, which will allow you to do something once the countdown is done. I've done something similar with a smaller-scale timer, with a well-written API. Note the complete: callback is hiding the countdown div, and showing the other.

With a little research, they say there IS an api, and you will get it when you purchase their product. Best of luck.

```js
var countdown = $("#countdown").countdown360({
    radius: 60,
    seconds: 10,
    label: ['sec', 'secs'],
    fontColor: '#FFFFFF',
    autostart: false,
    onComplete: function () {
      console.log('done');
      $("#countdown").hide();
      $(".completed-countdown").show();
    }
});

countdown.start();

$('#countdown').click(function() {
  countdown.extendTimer(2);
});
```

```css
.completed-countdown {
  display:none;
}
.completed-countdown img {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/johnschult/jquery.countdown360/master/dist/jquery.countdown360.min.js"></script>
<div id="countdown"></div>
<div class="completed-countdown">
<img src="https://media.giphy.com/media/l41m2ufxcKGSFGV8I/giphy.gif" />
</div>
```

That said, and doing a little digging, it looks like the callback is called onFinish. So you might go:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $(".countdown").circularCountdown({
       startDate: "2015/03/01 12:30:00",
       endDate: "2017/11/26 17:15:30",
       timeZone: +1,
       onFinish: function(){
           $(".countdown").hide();
       }
   });
});
```

Comment: thank you but I served for days, hours, and minutes and not for seconds ... thank you very much

Comment: and it has to be eliminated as the day circle reaches zero and so on for hours to minutes

Comment: So there's no functionality for that built into the flashBlue plugin. And again, I'm working from the assumption you're using the flashBlue plugin, as you haven't actually said. But you can create your own hook using setInterval -- take a look at https://jsfiddle.net/snowMonkey/p2txq32u/ to see this working. And scroll all the way to the bottom for the setInterval function that makes the code work.

Comment: Updated the code to set the time dynamically four hours from the current time. Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/snowMonkey/p2txq32u/1/  Do note, though, that this is based on the assumption you're using the flashBlue widget. And if you are, I really REALLY suggest you ask them if they have a better API.

Comment: Really thank you very much! I was very helpful was what I was interested in. thank you again

Comment: as I do once the coutdown has disappeared I wish I could compare another time, which at the time of the coutdown is not visible. I thank you in advance @Snowmonkey

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Do you have a fiddle or repl.it or something for what you've got?